# Can I declare and define static class variable in a same .CPP file?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In my .cpp I have a class declaration and definition both.There are errors when I try to initialize a string array using one of the way suggested.

```
class week
{
public:
    week();
    static const char * const days[];
}

week::week()
{
 const char * const week::days = {"monday" , "tuesday" "etc..."}
}
```

I am getting redefinition error for days variable which is valid. But I would like what changes I will need to do to above code in order to work in a same .cpp file.

Here I am not using header file to declare class. Both class declaration and definition lies in SAME .cpp file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the C++ file you should write

```
const char * const week::days[] = {"monday", ...};
//                            ^^  <- don't forget these
```

It should be in global scope, not in the constructor. The constructor should have nothing to do with static member initialization.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to do something like this:

```
class week
{
public:
    week();
    static const char * const days[];
};

week::week()
{

}

const char * const week::days[] = {"monday" , "tuesday", "etc..."};

void main()
{
    week w;
}
```

UPDATE:

Have a look at the few mistakes I corrected:

1. Added the `;` at the end of the class
2. Moved the initialization of the static variable `days` **outside** the class and added a `;` to the initialization statement as well.

Static variables are initialized in the global scope (after the class definition). The constructor is only used to initialize member variables of the **current** object instance.

Coming to your question about putting all of your code in the same (.cpp) file, the answer is yes. You can put all of your code in the same file and compile it and it will work.
However that's not recommended.
By convention, header (.h) files contain declarations and (.cpp) contain definitions.

So, refactoring the above code, I get the following files with the corresponding code:

**File:** week.h

```
class week
{
public:
    week();
    static const char * const days[];
};
```

**File:** week.cc (or week.cpp)

```
#include "week.h"
const char * const week::days[] = {"monday" , "tuesday", "etc..."};

week::week()
{

}
```

**File:** main.cc (or main.cpp)

```
#include "week.h"
void main()
{
    week w;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the static data member outside of a class function.

eg:

```
class week
{
public:
    week();
    static const char * const days[];
};

char * week::days[] = {"monday" , "tuesday" "etc..."};

week::week()
{
}
```

You will see the same problem if you split the class definition into a header file (.h/.hpp)

Comment: Not declare, but define. (The declaration of the member is in the class definition.)

Answer (score 0):

As a general guideline, never define member functions in header file unless they are explicitly designated as inline ( which means they should be good candidate for in-lining from compiler perspective also. )

When you make a function inline it depends on compiler whether it chooses it to make inline or not for some optimization reasons. There are two ways of declaring functions inline.

```
1) Implicit:-
Class Data
{
 public:
   void send()      
   {
   }
};
2) Explicit:-
class Data
{
  void send();
};
inline void Data::send()
{
}
```

Comment: How can I define them inside a class?

Comment: There are two ways:- 1) Class X { void send() { } }; . This is implicitly assumed as inline ( although depends on compiler ). 2) Class X {};     inline void X::send() { } ( You are requesting compiler to make it inline ).

Comment: please guide me to do that.

Comment: "never define member functions in cpp file"  What?  You seem to be suggesting that *all* code should be in header files.  You're going to have to defend that one.

Comment: that's my mistake.I apologize.